# UIAlertView prevent dimming surrounding screen

Tags: ios, uialertview

For a basic **UIAlertView**, anyone knows how to prevent from dimming surrounding screen when the alert dialog is showing up?

With iPhone SDK 6.0 I've been checking UIAlertView.h and there is this private struct _modalViewFlags with a set of bit fields, among which **dontDimBackground**. Seems to be storing a flag to the very functionality I'm searching for. Can't see a public method to set/reset this.

Comment: In this case, you probably can't. Do you need your piece of software to be accepted in the AppStore? Or are you free to use private APIs?

Comment: The software will go into the App Store, so I'm restricted to public APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to prevent the dimming of the background without using private APIs. You'll probably want to use a 3rd party alert view that allows more customizing.

[WCAlertView](https://github.com/m1entus/WCAlertView) includes options to set the background gradient color. If you set it to be `clearColor`, it should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I was interested in a native solution.